# Access items in enumerate by index

Tags: python

As part of a project, I need to reference specific values in an iterable by their index. Unfortunately, this iterable doesn't have a `__getitem__()` method defined, so I don't have a way of directly doing this. So far, I've been using `enumerate()` to get the indices, but unfortunately that doesn't give me a subscriptable object (for reasons that I don't understand, the package I'm working with really doesn't like it when I cast the enumerate to a list either, so that option's out). So far my best solution is this:

```
goodEvs=[(i,ev) for i,ev in enumerate(events) if i in flags]
```

where `flags` is a list of the indices that I want to keep. Unfortunately, iterating through all of `events` takes a very long time, so I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
goodEvs=[events[i] for i in flags]
```

but then I run into subscriptability problems. Sorry for the very weird and specific constraints, I think we're starting to stretch what this package can do (or I'm just bad at this). Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly can't you cast the iterable to a list?

Comment: The package we're using (the FWLite package for PyRoot, if that helps) is very finicky about this; whenever we try to, it assembles the list fine, but crashes when we try to reference an item from it.

Comment: You could also just subclass the class missing the `__getitem__` and add it yourself?

Comment: If you can use the events in `goodEvs`, then you should be able to use the elements of `list(events)` too. It sounds like either `goodEvs` has the same problems and you just haven't noticed yet, or `list(events)` is fine and you mistakenly blamed some other bug on it.

Comment: `goodEvs` does also have those problems, the actual code that works isn't exactly that, but follows the same structure (iterates through `enumerate(events)` and works with only the items with the index we want). If it would be more helpful, I can post a stripped-down version of our full working code.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but… when an iterable doesn't have `__getitem__`, the two most common reasons are that it's an iterator (like `enumerate`), or that it has no meaningful order and can only guarantee consistency within a single iteration (like `set`). There are other possibilities, like a linked list, but they're not as common. Anyway, you probably need to know _why_ there's no `__getitem__`, and what the implications of that are, before you can figure out how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: One more thing: are you sure the problem is that iterating through `events` takes too long, and not that looking up `i in flags` each time takes too long? If `flags` is a list, and a big one, that's a linear search you're doing zillions of times; replacing it with a set might be all you need here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that advanced with python. How would I use a set here?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the problem actually runs deeper than what I've been asking about. Thanks so much to everyone for the fast response, but I think I need to go back to the drawing board. I'll be closing this topic as soon as I can figure out how to